# Decimales en HTML, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una duda, estoy haciendo una calculadora en HTML y JavaScript, y mi problema es que cuando por ejemplo voy a sumar numeros que digito en la pagina web con decimales por ejemplo 12.3 + 10 lo que pasa es que me devuelbe 22 y no 22.3, entonces si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradeceria bastante

Comment: Y como seria tu codigo, para ver que es lo que esta mal?

Comment: Porfavor lee [ask]. y bienvenido al sitio, realizar el [tour] tambien porfavor.

Comment: Seguramente estás convirtiendo a enteros con `parseInt()` y solo necesites cambiar por `parseFloat()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Triby si era eso ^^

Comment: Y perdon si no me hice entender bien pero igual gracias tratare de mejorar mis preguntas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código podría quedar así:

**index.html**

```
<input id="first" value="12.3"> + <input id="second" value="10"> = <input 
id="result">

<script>
function add(){
    var first=parseFloat($("#first").val());
    var second=parseFloat($("#second").val());
    $("#result").val(+(first+second).toFixed(2));
}

add();
$("input").blur(add);
</script>
```

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Creo que es conveniente aclarar el uso de JQuery y de métodos como blur, ya que el OP no expone si lo usa o no, aqui puedes ver [answer]

Comment: Sí perfecto; muchas gracias por la aclaración!